# Deprecated Error shows up in header on website running 4.0.3

Tags: upgrade

Running 4.0.3

After entering a new "News" item this is displayed on the site. It remains even though I deleted the News item.
ttps://prnt.sc/pe2ppt

```
Deprecated The each () function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls.
Severity: E_Deprecated
Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started atee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:111)
```

It also said there is a newer version but when I upgrade I get this Message
https://prnt.sc/pe2r05

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve error of `each()` function is deprecated you need to try `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    //your code
}
```

This will solve your problem.